# Why binary search is not working on my test?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, binary-search

I have just written a binary search on c++, using arrays, but it isn't working for all of my tests.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int bSearch(int arr[], int item);

int main() {
    int testArr[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 20};
    int result = bSearch(testArr, 18);
    cout << "The result of binary search is " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}

int bSearch(int arr[], int item) {
    int start = 0;
    int middle(0), guess(0);
    int finish = sizeof(arr);

    while(start <= finish) {
        middle = (start + finish) / 2;
        guess = arr[middle];

        if(guess == item)
            return middle;
        else if(guess > item)
            finish = middle - 1;
        else
            start = middle + 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Can you explain me, why is it so?

Comment: Please add some information regarding what doesn't work. Ideally show us your results.

Comment: What test do it fail?

Comment: `sizeof` returns the size of an *element* (in bytes) of the array, so not the number of *elements* in the array.

Comment: @PabloJeken the result of this test is -1 (we try to find the element which equals to 18, there is 18 in array, but the result of searching is position -1).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you very much, I'll try to use another method for getting the size of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bSearch`, the parameter `arr` is not an array, but a pointer to an `int`.  There is no information on if it points to an array of ints or the number of elements may be part of such an array.so `sizeof(arr)` will be the size of a pointer (typically 4 or 8).

You'll need to pass number of elements the array holds to `bSearch`, or use one of the standard containers that track the size (`std::vector` or `std::array`).